# ASCII graphs in LaTeX document?

Tags: graphs, input-encodings

I have ASCII graphs which I want to get nicer like the below. How can I embed ASCII graphs nicely converted to LaTeX document?

**Input**

```
    11              11
01      10  <-> 10      01
    00              00
```

**Intended Output**

[image]

Comment: Simple `verbatim`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino sure it works but next trying to get something nicer directly from ASCII.

Comment: @hhh: Can you give us an example of how such a nicer graph would look like? Do you think of something like an ASCII-based frontend for drawing graphs with "proper" non-ASCII edges?

Comment: @Ruedi I added a possible visualisation.

Comment: How is the parser supposed to know to add edges between the nodes? And how it is supposed to know when _not_ to add edges between the nodes? If you are flexible to using a better-formed syntax, maybe you can consider `graphviz`? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/graphviz